# SilverStripe UploadField UI update on success

Tags: file-upload, silverstripe

In the [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/#change-detection) it talks about detecting a change in the upload field and then updating the UI accordingly like highlighting the save button.

I've looked around the web, documentation, and been through a lot of the code (although not all) and can't find out how I would implement such a function.

Basically I'd like to write a JS function to do something that would be called when an upload is successful. Can this be done via this function?

Comment: Can you please expand on your question with more detail or some code examples?

It would be possible to add your own JS and run it at the right time, as per Silverstripe's Javascript Development documentation https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/javascript_development/. I also see that `UploadFile.js` has a 'dirty' event that is triggered in the widget's `_onDone` method i.e `this.element.closest('form').trigger('dirty');`.

Comment: @jakxnz It's the `dirty` trigger that I don't fully understand. I've never come across them and searching only brings up angular (which I know SS doesn't use).

Comment: Assuming you've establish the correct scope for the CMS edit `form`, you can setup a callback on the dirty event with `form.on('dirty', function() { });`

Comment: @jakxnz this is for a frontend form, not within the CMS.